# How to reset the password on a Windows 7 netbook?

Tags: windows-7, passwords, password-recovery

I forgot my password on my Windows 7 netbook and I don't have a password reset disk. How can I get in?

It's a brand new laptop so I wouldn't mind doing a system restore but I can't even do that since I don't have a CD drive and I don't know the password.

Answer (score 3):

In XP there is usually a hidden administrator account created when you install the system. This is an account that can only be accessed when you boot into `safe mode`, and by default it has no password.

You could try booting into Windows 7's safe mode and see if this is still true. To enter safe mode, simply hit F8 while your computer is booting up. See [this page](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial61.html) for more info.

Comment: I don't believe it is true any longer though that would have worked nicely.

Answer (score 2):

In XP, you can access the hidden administrator account in normal bootup by hitting ctrl-alt-del twice.  A dialog like Windows 2000 will popup allowing you to enter the username administrator.  If there is no password associated with that account, it should be a no brainer.  I would have commented but don't have that privilege yet.

Windows 7 doesn't allow you to use this method.  You can try booting into safe mode to see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try [KON-BOOT](http://www.piotrbania.com/all/kon-boot/):

> Kon-Boot for Windows enables logging
>   in to any password protected machine
>   profile without without any knowledge
>   of the password.

You will need to follow one of [these](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/kon-boot-from-usb) [tutorials](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2009/05/11/burn-iso-image-to-usb-flash-pen-drive-kon-boot-to-usb/) to make a KON-BOOT-able USB drive.